# C# WPF Stackpanel layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a stackpanel in a treeviewitem. I'm trying to get my picture next to my checkbox and the text next to my picture box but I don't know how to do that. Currently this is happening:

[image: http://img854.imageshack.us/i/naamloosl.png/]

This is my code:

```
ComboBoxItem tempComboItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();

        StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Width = 260;
        Label labelTitle = new Label();
        Label labelStatus = new Label();
        Image newImage = new Image();



        newImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageTextBox1.Text));
        newImage.Width = 85;
        newImage.Height = 65;

        panel.Children.Add(newImage);

        labelTitle.Content = itemTextBox1.Text;
        panel.Children.Add(labelTitle);



        labelStatus.Content = "Beschikbaar";
        panel.Children.Add(labelStatus);


        labelStatus.Foreground = Brushes.Lime;

        cbox.Content = panel;

        TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
        newChild.Header = cbox;
```

Can someone help me out.

I want the checkbox and image and text to be horizontal. I can do with:  `panel.Orientation.`

**But** the two text labels on the right, I want them vertical, one below the other.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Wouldn't it be much easier to use `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: Indeed. Use the put the xaml from my answer in a DataTemplate and assign it to the ItemTemplate property of the Treeview (do not forget to using `{Binding }` instead of hard coded values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make the following XAML: (If you need help to turn this into code let me know)

```
    <CheckBox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                   Width="85"
                   Height="65" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="Title" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="beschikbaar" />
        </Grid>
    </CheckBox>
```

Comment: +1 layout belongs in the xaml. This is WPF after all, not winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply mean you want `Horizontal` orientation?

If so, try the following:

```
panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Though, I fear you actually may require more intervention than just setting this property; lets see.

Comment: no not all needs to be horizontal, the 2 text labels have to be vertical

Comment: @anony g:OK, then you'll need more elements within your `StackPanel` in order to accommodate that - a `Grid`, for instance; and lay out your elements even more finely in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <DockPanel>
    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
      <TextBlock>My Text One</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock>beschikbaar</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="myImage.png" />
  </DockPanel>
```

This is a simple way to achieve the effect.  From here you can easily adjust the vertical alignments to your liking.  You can also easily do this in code, but I would recommend that you stick to XAML for layout based tasks.